# Passing R script variables into a batch script

Tags: r, batch-file

In an R script, I'm executing a batch file inside of a for loop.

```
for (i in 1:2){
    shell(shQuote("\\\\NETWORK\\PATH\\TO\\THE\\FILE.BAT", "cmd"))
}
```

The batch script creates data and moves it to a SQL table that looks like this:

```
|  Name | Version | Category | Value | Number | Replication |
|:-----:|:-------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|:-----------:|
| File1 | 1.0     | Time     |   123 |      1 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Size     |   456 |      1 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Time     |   312 |      1 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Size     |   645 |      1 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Time     |   369 |      1 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.0     | Size     |   258 |      1 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Time     |   741 |      1 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.0     | Size     |   734 |      1 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Time     |   997 |      2 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Size     |   997 |      2 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Time     |   438 |      2 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Size     |   735 |      2 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Time     |   786 |      2 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.1     | Size     |   486 |      2 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Time     |   379 |      2 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.1     | Size     |   943 |      2 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Time     |   123 |      3 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Size     |   456 |      3 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Time     |   312 |      3 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Size     |   645 |      3 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Time     |   369 |      3 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.2     | Size     |   258 |      3 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Time     |   741 |      3 |           2 |
| File2 | 1.2     | Size     |   734 |      3 |           2 |
| File1 | 1.3     | Time     |   997 |      4 |           1 |
| File1 | 1.3     | Size     |   997 |      4 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.3     | Time     |   438 |      4 |           1 |
| File2 | 1.3     | Size     |   735 |      4 |           1 |
```

However, I'd like for the `Number` and `Replication` column to be declared in the R script, not the batch file.

I know I can do that like this:

```
Replication <- i
Number <- as.integer(sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select max(Number) from Table"))
Number<-ifelse(is.na(Number), 1, Number + 1)
```

My question though is how can I pass these variables into the batch script? Can I pass parameters into the batch script?

So that in my batch script, I could have something similar to this:

```
set Rep=[Replication variable from R]
set Num=[Number variable from R]
```

Comment: are you asking how to pass command-line parameters to batch script?  in that case, the command-line arguments are accessible with `%1`, `%2`, etc.

Comment: @nongkrong I think that might be what I'm looking for. I'm kind of shaky on the concept. I'm trying to pass variables in an R script to a batch (cmd line) script that is executed in the R script as shown above.

Comment: Any sane programmer would rewrite this to have **one** script take the parameters, query the database (R can talk to all of them) and then run the results.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Lets pretend that I'm not sane. I'd really like to get this up and running within the next few hours rather than rewriting it all. I can do all of that later.

Comment: just do `sprintf("myBatch.bat %d %d", Replication, Number)` in your `shell` call, and then in the batch script, `Rep=%1` and `Num=%2`.

Comment: @Nongkrong could you show how sprintf fits into the shell syntax? In other words, am I going to write it like this? `shell(shQuote(sprintf("\\\\NETWORK\\PATH\\TO\\THE\\File.bat", %d, %d, Replication, Number), "cmd"))` Also, what is the significance of `%d`? instead of `%1` or `%2`? I can't find this in R `sprintf`. documentation.

Comment: “Can I pass parameters into the batch script?” — you *are* already doing this (`"cmd"`). You can just pass in more.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Okay, my script looks like this: 
`a<-1` and `b<-2` then `shell(shQuote(paste("C:\\Documents\\file.bat", a, b), "cmd"))`. Weirdly, if I turn echo on, then I can see the parameters showing up in the command window. However, if I test this with say `echo %1`, I get `ECHO is on`. If I say `echo Var1: %1` then I get `Var1:`.